# Do we need to edit tags to add German tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

From recent tag edits

- [Is "to make one sigh" properly translated as "seufzen machen" or as "machen seufzen?"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/is-to-make-one-sigh-properly-translated-as-seufzen-machen-or-as-machen-seuf)
- [How are we polite without using "bitte"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/how-are-we-polite-without-using-bitte)
- [Woher kommt die Redewendung "über den Tellerrand sehen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-uber-den-tellerrand-sehen)

I feel we need to discuss the necessity for German tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/107/tag-synonym-requests http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/209/dont-edit-german-tags-to-english-tags http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/106/which-language-to-use-in-tags http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in

Comment: @userunknown: I deliberately did not link to the questions on tags we already have. There was quite some consensus  that for having English tags visible we need to create synonyms for upcoming German tags. My question here addresses **tag edits** to introduce new German tags when they were not there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tags should preferably be in German to help people to learn German.

Comment: Mainly to help people, who don't speak English very well. Presenting 5 alternative answers, but with unbalanced reasoning, looks like suggestive manipulation for me, if all of them are written by the same person, and not marked as community wiki.

Comment: @userunknown: what would be the benefit of a community wiki here?

Comment: Wenn Du 4 entgegengesetzte Antworten gibst ist offenbar, dass diese nicht Deine Meinung darstellen, sondern wohl nur eine davon. Wenn Du also eine Abstimmung zwischen allen Alternativen herbeiführen willst, dann sollten diese Alternativen ausgewogen dargestellt werden. Ich betrachte die Begründung, dass man mit Tags den Leuten Deutsch beibringt, für eine üble, polemische Sabotage an dieser Antwortalternative, denn der Grund für deutche Synonyme ist natürlich, dass man Deutsch schon kann, aber eben vielleicht kein Englisch.

Comment: If you present 4 opposite Answeralternatives, you obviously don't promote all of them. If you like to perform a decision making, you should present the alternatives in a neutral form. But the possibility to vote for German tags is poissioned with a bizzare rationale. Of course the reason to use German tags is, that you know German, but maybe don't know English/don't know it that well.

Comment: @userunknown: don't hesitate to give your own unbiased answer then.

Answer (score 3):

French SE has [french tags](https://french.stackexchange.com/tags), why can't you have german ones?

If the concern is "understanding" for nonnative speakers, I can suggest 2 simple solutions:

1. *Add the translation in the tag excerpt*. This way when you hover on the tag, you can see the translation. And then in the Tag Wiki, you explain what they are used for.
2. *Do the opposite of 1*. Add the translation in the Tag Wiki, and propose the tag-usage in the excerpt.

Comment: I don't know why we started with English tags. The site description certainly allows for German tags: "German Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for **speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language** and translation. " (except for cross-site tag sets, but the SE team is apparently fine with french.SE having it that way)

Comment: As soon as you have tags in more than one language it will be impossible to retrieve all answers on a topic by a search engine. Tags are not very important for us but they are for [search engines](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/249/23). Google will very likely use English when dealing with a SE site.

Comment: @Takkat French SE is not having problems on that. Try asking the mods, they could help you. What I'm saying is that you don't need to deny that without even trying (assuming you want the German tags).

Comment: They made this [meta post](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/59/should-question-tags-be-in-english-or-french-or-both)...

Comment: @Alenanno: I am perfectly fine with English only tags. But my tags were  edited by someone else to add German tags - in addition to the English tags. Because I do not know why this was done I started a discussion here (rather than just rolling back the tag edits).

Comment: @Takkat I see. :) Then we have to decide whether we want only English or only German tags, it would be confusing to have both.

Comment: @Alenanno: that exactly was my intention.

Comment: @Takkat I thought so... :P

Comment: French.SE has a policy of bilingual tag wiki excerpts and bodies (though we're rather behind on that) and of having French tag names with English synonyms (which we mostly do).

Answer (score 1):

Tags should always be in English to be conform with other SE sites. German tags should be replaced by appropriate English tags.

Comment: Using English tags makes the most sense to me, with the addition that [synonyms should be created for German tags when they are removed](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/309/tag-synonym-annoyance). With tag synonyms, questions tagged _übersetzung_ are automatically tagged _translation_ instead.

Comment: @TimN: To create a tag synonym, you have to create a tag first. This is what I made, since "Redewendung" wasn't in the tag list, and could not be created as a synonym. Please read my answer here too: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/308/266

Comment: Does this answer even fit to your question?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

Yes, tags should preferably be in German to help people with limited English experience.

---

#### Ja

Deutsche Schlüsselwörter sind das, was man auf einer Webseite zur Deutschen Sprache erwarten darf, denn die Seite ist für Leute, die sich für Deutsch interessieren; somit ist der größte gemeinsame Nenner *Deutsch*.

Viele Fachbegriffe gehen über das Abiturwissen Englisch hinaus, ohne dass irgendwo Abiturwissen Englisch als erste Fremdsprache Zugangsvorraussetzung für diese Seite wäre. Vielleicht hat die Seite noch wenige Besucher aus Osteuropa, Asien, Afrika und Südamerika, wo User, die schon Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen wollen, nicht außerdem auch noch Englisch sprechen müssen; insbesondere nicht auf einem Niveau, auf dem man 'idioms', 'diacritics', 'prussian' oder 'connotations' versteht.

Die Englische Sprache wirkt hier wie eine Barriere, die weniger Gebildete effektiv ausschließt, weil diese mit der Bedienung der Seite ohne fremde Hilfe nicht zurechtkommen, oder durch mehrfache Konsultation ihrer Wörterbücher im Arbeitsfluss unangenehm aufgehalten werden.

Wie man sieht fahren die Franzosen prächtig mit französischen Tags: https://french.stackexchange.com/tags

Das Argument, das Internet sei im wesentlichen Englisch, ist in diesem Zusammenhang ziemlich dumm, denn das ist es natürlich nicht, sondern das ist ein Eindruck den man sich selbst dadurch verschafft, das man entsprechende Seiten besucht oder nicht besucht - d.h. den Eindruck produziert man durch sein Verhalten selbst.
Der inhaltliche Fokus auf die deutsche Sprache erlaubt aber eigentlich allen Leuten mit Fragen zu dieser hier teilzunehmen.

Synonyme in die Gegenrichtung, so dass man mit dem englischen Begriff das deutsche Synonym findet, sind allerdings willkommen.

Comment: I didn't know it would take such a long translation in German... :P Can you expand the English one and include what you said in German? Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 0):

Questions should preferably be tagged in English. If a German tag exists this should always be added to the tag line.

Comment: Even if you want to hide the german tag, you have to create them first, and you can only create them by adding them somewhere. And as long as they aren't accepted synonyms, they will not be hidden. So adding them to the tagline is the only way to produce them.

Comment: @userunknown: why not ask for them [here in meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/107/23)?

Comment: a) There is a process set up, to create such synonyms - why should I visit a meta thread? And if I visit the meta - how are synonyms created then? The same way as if I created them right away, I suspect. -- Wieso soll ich nicht die von der Software vorgesehene Methode wählen, sondern einen Metathread? Und dann, wenn ich im Thread Zustimmung finde, wie wird dann ein Synonym erzeugt? Nicht auf die gleiche Weise?

Comment: @userunknown: I saw your synonym requests from yesterday now. Moderators have to check the list manually to see new requests, which arguably isn't the best method for small sites. I'm approving them right now. To speed up the process, you're welcome to edit or answer the meta post that Takkat linked to, or just post another meta question.

Comment: @TimN: But that's a bad process. You have to explain it to every new user. And I don't like to visit so many places, just to add a translation for a tag, which should be there in the first place. Tags aren't only useful for search engines. Maybe Takkat does not use them, but I like to search for tags too, and AFAIK, it is one of the intentions of tags, to be used to search for them here. And, afaik, the process of upvoting synonyms is not restricted to moderators only. You need some reputation in that tag.

Comment: @TimN: Das ist aber ein bürokratischer, unhandlicher Prozess, der einem das Anlegen von Tagübersetzungen vollends verleidet, wenn man noch eine zusätzliche Seite besuchen muss. Dass Tags nur für externe Suchmaschinen gedacht sind halte ich im übrigen für falsch. Zudem muss das komplizierte Verfahren wieder und wieder neuen Usern erklärt werden, wenn es nicht Teil des automatischen Prozesses ist, und in den FAQ steht. Außerdem ist der Prozess des Akzeptierens von Synonymen nicht auf Moderatoren beschränkt, sondern jeder mit 5 Reputationspunkten im Tag darf dieses als Synonym aufwerten.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why tag edits would be required to bring in German tags. There is a synonym system: for each English tag, provide a German synonym (or vice versa).

French.SE started out with French tags and English synonyms. Spanish.SE started out in the other direction, then [switched](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/shall-we-switch-to-spanish-language-tags). Russian.SE has had Russian tags with English synonyms since early on when Cyrillic tags were made possible.

The reputation requirements on tag synonyms makes them practically unworkable outside Stack Overflow, so it's mostly up to ♦moderators to create the synonyms.

Answer (score -1):

No, we do not need German tags.

Users that cannot speak English are welcome to choose a German tag synonym if available but we should not edit tags to add a German tag synonym.