# Do we need Unicode tags for umlauts and 'ß'?

Tags: discussion

There was some consent about tags being preferably in English but we do have some tags synonymized with the English counterpart, where the *umlaut* could not be rendered correctly:

[uebersetzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uebersetzung) [ubersetzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubersetzung) [anfuehrungszeichen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anfuehrungszeichen)

Unicode support for tags is possible, and we should discuss the need of activating this here.

It would also be nice to have some good examples why we need tags with Unicode-support.

Comment: It would be "nice to have" but when will there be a button to switch all user-interface text (menus, help messages, etc.) to German? You should get together with your fellow mods on french.SE and spanish.SE to start a hunger strike.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: it is an *"already possible to have"* feature (see e.g. http://russian.stackexchange.com/tags) but it has to be actively enabled in case we need it - that's why I started this discussion.

Comment: Besides having ä, ö, ü and ß: what are the advantages of enabling that feature. What are the possibly disadvantages why we should avoid using unicode?

Answer (score 5):

No idea what's there to discuss.

1. We speak a language that isn't covered by ASCII or whatever extension thereof we are using.
2. You already provide two examples for why we need another charset, be it Unicode or something else.
3. [The community tends to agree that German synonyms would be nice.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/do-we-need-to-edit-tags-to-add-german-tag-synonyms)

What other examples or discussion are required?